# What does those return mean in Python?

Tags: python, return

This is a question from a book but the `return` confuses me.
It has a function with three variables and return stuff below:

```
return (str(a) if b == 0 or a != 1  else '') + ('' if b == 0 else c +('+'+str(b) if b != 1 else ''))
```

Can anyone separate it into normal way to make it clearer to me? 
The parentheses with + confused me a lot.

Comment: This is using ternary form; see here for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator

Comment: which part of it is confusing you? try breaking the statement up remembering that brackets are resolved first. `if x else y` is effectively python's way of putting an if else block on a single line - the ternary operation

Comment: i am  clear with condition if and else which is those in the parentheses. but the second part (  + ()) confused me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what the code is doing:

```
def someFunc(a,b,p):
    if b==0 or a!=1:
        part1 = str(a)
    else:
        part1 = ''
    if p==0:
        part2 = ''
    else:
        if b!=1:
            part2 = c + '+'+str(b)
        else:
            part2 = ''
    return part1 + part2
```

Comment: @BillLynch: because `elsif` is not a thing in python. I didn't use `elif`, just to keep things super simple and readable for OP

Answer (score 0):

The statement returns a string.

The first part evaluates to `str(a)` if b is 0 or a is not 1. If that statement is false, it evaluates to ".

The second part evaluates to " if b is 0. If that statement is false, it evaluates to c + '+' `str(b)` if b is not 1. If **that** statement is false, it evaluates to ".

So you either get "", `str(a) + "`, `str(a) + str(c) + '+'(str(b))`, or `" + str(c) + '+'(str(b))`.